# how to get the env values declared inline in dockerfile from run env parameter instead in docker

Tags: docker, automation, dockerfile, magento2

I have successfully setup docker container for magento2 and this is how I am passing the database setup value to the magento2 cli command by setting the env value inline as bellow.

```
FROM docker-php
#mysqql setup
ENV DB_HOST 172.17.0.2
ENV DB_NAME mydb1
ENV DB_USER prakash 
ENV DB_PASSWORD password

#start running the magento commands to install
RUN cd /usr/html/bin  && \
     ./magento setup:config:set  --db-host=$DB_HOST --db-name=$DB_NAME --db-user=$DB_USER --db-password=$DB_PASSWORD
```

How do I make this such that these value can be received  successfully  by passing it via on run like bellow 
**`docker  run -e DB_HOST="" -e DB_NAME="" -e  DB_USER="" -e DB_PASSWORD="" <build-image-id>`**

Saw few post describing how these can be achieved but not able to figure out  the proper way

Comment: What is your actual problem?  The `-e` options should propagate the values you specify into the environment, overriding any default setting in the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @tripleee the environment vars are not consumed by the RUN command

Comment: Huh? They are set when you run `docker build` or what have you.

Comment: @tripleee `docker build --help`. No option for `-e`. You can't consume them from cli, only hardcoded in dockerfile

Comment: Why would you want that anyway? The OP is asking about `docker run` as far as I can tell.

Comment: @tripleee Yes but he is consuming those values in the RUN command in the dockerfile. check the code.

Comment: i want to pass those values during the docker  run just like how mysql docker is run by  passing the hostname and other details .

Answer (score 0):

You are using the ENV values inside the `RUN` command. The command is executed when **building** the container and not when running it. This works fine when you hardcode the env values inside the dockerfile, however you can't pass them on the cli.

Thus you have to pass the `RUN` command build args. These arguments are consumed when building the container and thus when the RUN command is executed.

```
FROM docker-php
#mysqql setup
ARG DB_HOST
ARG DB_NAME
ARG DB_USER 
ARG DB_PASSWORD

#start running the magento commands to install
RUN cd /usr/html/bin  && \
     ./magento setup:config:set  --db-host=$DB_HOST --db-name=$DB_NAME --db-user=$DB_USER --db-password=$DB_PASSWORD
```

Then the image can be built using:

```
docker build --build-args DB_HOST=172.17.0.2 DB_NAME=mydb1 DB_USER=prakash DB_PASSWORD=password -t <image-name> .
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass those value during with run not with the build by passing it as -e  value

Comment: Again, ur `RUN` executes when building the image using `docker build`. You have to build the image before running it

Comment: But building with one set of values and then running  `docker run -e var=value` with a different set of values does work, and overrides whatever defaults where in the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @tripleee yes, but at that point the `RUN` command has already executed with the first set of values

Comment: Oh okay, you are speculating that the OP would like the `RUN` to happen when you `docker run`, not when you `docker build`.

Comment: Yes we want the users to run it passing the necessary credentials. Developers would just like to run it

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung To summarize. If you want to pass them during `docker run ...`, those values won't be reflected in the command `./magento setup:config:set  --db-host=$DB_HOST --db-name=$DB_NAME --db-user=$DB_USER --db-password=$DB_PASSWORD`.

Comment: Ok I got that but where should i move this commands to reflect during the run. What design changes should i be doing

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung It either the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`. Those instructions execute on `docker run` and will detect `-e` arguments being passed on the cli.

Comment: I added it to CMD like this and passed a value with -e but nothing happens its not running the installation `CMD ./magento setup:config:set  --db-host=$DB_HOST --db-name=$DB_NAME --db-user=$DB_USER --db-password=$DB_PASSWORD
`

Comment: I don't think that would be the right solutions too as that is what starts my magento2 setup. confused what shall be the right way thanks